# Getting the updated value of Spin Control

Tags: mfc

Im using a spin button and want to read it's position.
I've overwritten `OnDeltaposSpin(...)` , but then i have to evaluate the `NMHDR`. If I set `*pResult=0`, it will do the calculations for me, but my value lags behind.

```cpp
void CClass::OnDeltaposSpin(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);
    *pResult = 0;
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    // I want to use the data here
}
```

So if the Spin is initially 0, the first click won't do anything to my data, the second click gets it to 1, and so on.

Is there another message i can handle that triggers after `UDN_DELTAPOS` that would work like `EN_CHANGE` for other controls? Or can i tell the spin control to use the `*pResult` to do it's calculations inside `OnDeltaposSpin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like UDN_DELTAPOS is used for overriding the position change amount, or preventing a change, but the actual change happens with a WM_VSCROLL (or WM_HSCROLL) message. I suspect those might be the messages you would need to handle to get the results....

(I'm basing this on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/udn-deltapos) doc.)

Comment: This indeed is what i'm searching for. It's just more complicated than i ecpected... Why is there this message for all possible scrollbars (including spin controls) when this could just be a seperate message for each individual scollbar/spinctrl?